# Can I get the success/failure of a task into a property if ContinueOnError="true" is used?

Tags: msbuild

I'm executing a task in msbuild:

```
<MyTask ContinueOnError="true" OtherParam="Cheese"/>

<PropertyGroup>
  <MyTaskResult>????how do I set this????</MyTaskResult>
<PropertyGroup>
```

I want to get the result of MyTask into a property (it's Execute method returns a bool) so I can test it and conditionally do stuff. Is this possible?

Thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could modify your task to put its results in an output parameter.

Comment: Thanks, yes, you're right. Phew, good job I've got the source code. I'm surprised there doesn't seem to be any other way.